# How to pass a string to a method that decodes a string64?

Tags: c#, string

I'm using a web service in Windows Phone7 Application(VS2010),

the service has a method that validates user name and password, but after I get the user name and password in textboxes from end-user and call the service, the validation throws an exception like this:

> FaultException was unhandled
>
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. --->                                   System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.
>     at System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32 inputLength, Byte* >startDestPtr, Int32 destLength)
>
> at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
>
> at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
>
> at myService.Mobile.Decode(String str)
>
> ....
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Well, basically the exception tells me `invalid length for base-64 char array or string.` It works when I pass a string that is four chars or multiples of four.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: How are you calling the service?

Comment: I'm using soap client if you meant this.

Comment: You would need to Base-64 encode it and send it to the service, as per @Marc Gravell answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method clearly expects base-64, which is a way of encoding arbitrary binary as an encoded string. The interesting question, then, is: what bytes do they expect? A reasonable first guess might be UTF-8, in which case:

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalString);
string base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

This seems a very unusual way of passing around a username, though! Are you *sure* this is talking about the username?

Comment: @jackjop I have to emphasize: this is an unusual approach by whoever wrote that API